# A basic question on open cover and compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $u=\{u_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $[a,b], a <b $. Let $S=\{r \in [a,b]$ such that $[a,r]$ is covered by some finite collection of open sets belonging to $u\}$. Is $S$ non-empty ? How ?

Comment: this was trivial. So deleting it.

Comment: or you could just accept an answer and /or post how you did it and move on, may not be trivial for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some $\alpha$ with $a\in u_\alpha$, hence also some $[a,r]\subseteq u_\alpha$ and then $[a,r]\subseteq S$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $u_{\alpha} \ni a$.